# Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355). Not able to read values in LINQ collection

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am trying to get all users name from Active Directory using PricipalContext. I can able to get the results on the IEnumurable variable as principalSearchResult using following code. But I am not able to read the results under principalSearchResult.

While trying to read the results from principalSearchResult , it will populate error message like **PrincipalOperation Exception was unhandled by users code: Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355).**

I don't know about this error and I am unable to read the values in the search result.

Here is my code:

```
 PrincipalContext ouContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, AD.ServerDomain, AD.LDAPUser, AD.LDAPPasswoprd);
 UserPrincipalEx userpricipalex = new UserPrincipalEx(ouContext);

 PrincipalSearcher mySearch = new PrincipalSearcher(userpricipalex);
 mySearch.QueryFilter = userpricipalex;

 IEnumerable<UserPrincipalEx> principalSearchResult = mySearch.FindAll().Cast <UserPrincipalEx>();

 var s = (from user in oPrincipalSearchResult      //Here I am getting the exception
                                   select new User
                                   {
                                    DisplayName=user.DisplayName,
                                    EmailAddress=user.EmailAddress
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
                                    });
```

How can I resolve this error and read the values in that IEnumurable collection without exception.

Answer (score -1):

The Domain Users built-in group will have all the ad users, so you can query all ad users details like shown below. Here i am storing the details in a DataTable. You can also store them as list of custom business objects. Hope this helps!!

---

```
string groupName="Domain Users";
using (GroupPrincipal objGroupPrincipal = GetGroupPrincipal(FQDN, AOuserName, AOpassword, groupName))
            {
                if (objGroupPrincipal != null)
                    using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> objPrincipalSearchResult = objGroupPrincipal.GetMembers(false))
                    {
                        objPrincipalSearchResult.ToList<Principal>().FindAll(p => p != null).Cast<UserPrincipal>().ToList<UserPrincipal>()
                            .ForEach(delegate(UserPrincipal objUserPrincipal)
                            {
                                DataRow drUser = dtUsers.NewRow();
                                drUser["displayname"] = objUserPrincipal.DisplayName;
                                drUser["UserName"] = objUserPrincipal.SamAccountName;
                                drUser["Domain"] = FQDN;
                                drUser["AccountActive"] = objUserPrincipal.IsAccountLockedOut();
                                drUser["FirstName"] = "";
                                drUser["initials"] = objUserPrincipal.MiddleName;
                                drUser["LastName"] = objUserPrincipal.Surname;
                                drUser["mail"] = objUserPrincipal.EmailAddress;
                                drUser["telephoneNumber"] = objUserPrincipal.VoiceTelephoneNumber;
                                drUser["LastLogOn"] = Convert.ToString(objUserPrincipal.LastLogon);
                                drUser["ADUserPath"] = Convert.ToString(objUserPrincipal.DistinguishedName);                                   
                                drUser["AccExpiryDate"] = Convert.ToString(objUserPrincipal.AccountExpirationDate);
                                drUser["PwdExpiryDate"] = "";
                                dtUsers.Rows.Add(drUser);
                            });


                    }
            }
```

And the sub methods are

```
public static GroupPrincipal GetGroupPrincipal(string FQDN, string AOuserName, string AOpassword, string groupName)
    {
        GroupPrincipal objGroupPrincipal = null;
        objGroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(GetPrincipalContext(FQDN, AOuserName, AOpassword), IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);
        return objGroupPrincipal;
    }
public static PrincipalContext GetPrincipalContext(string FQDN, string AOuserName, string AOpassword)
    {
        PrincipalContext objPrincipalContext = null;
       objPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, FQDN, AOuserName, AOpassword);
        return objPrincipalContext;
    }
```